# If $f(x)=f(x+5)$, is $\int f(x) dx=\int f(x+5) dx$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, functions

> Given a function $f$ such that $f(x)=f(x+5)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. If $\int_1^5 f(x) dx=3$ and $\int_{-5}^{-4} f(x)dx=-2$, find $\int_5^{15} f(x)dx$.

Here's my attempt. Let $\int f(x) dx=F(x)$. Since $f(x)=f(x+5)$, then $\int f(x) dx=\int f(x+5) dx$ or we can say that $F(x)=F(x+5)$. Next, observe that

1. $F(-4)=F(-4+5)=F(1)$
2. $F(-5)=F(-5+5)=F(0)=F(0+5)=F(5)$

Then, we get $F(5)-F(1)=3$ and $F(1)-F(5)=-2$. But we will get nothing. I am worried that $F(x)\neq F(x+5)$.

Comment: You cannot use primitive functions as you don't even know if $f$  is continuous.

Comment: Ahh I see. So how to solve that problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use any results involving primitive function as you are not given continuity. Rather, we make use of the following equality that always hold:

$$\int_a^b f(x) dx = \int_{a-c}^{b-c} f(x+c) dx$$

In particular, the case $c=5$ interests us because we then obtain
$$\int_a^b f(x) dx = \int_{a-5}^{b-5} f(x) dx$$
Hence, making use of this observations multiple times, we obtain:

\begin{align}\int_5^{15} f(x) dx &=\int_0^{10}f(x)dx \\
&= 2 \int_0^5 f(x) dx\\ 
&= 2\left(\int_0^1 f(x) dx + \int_1^4 f(x) dx\right)\\
&= 2\left(\int_{-5}^{-4}f(x)dx + \int_1^4 f(x) dx\right) \\
&= 2 (-2+3) = 2\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\int_{5}^{15} f(x) dx &= \int_{5}^{10} f(x) dx + \int_{10}^{15} f(x) dx \\
&= \int_{0}^{5} f(x) dx + \int_{0}^{5} f(x) dx \\
&=2 \cdot \int_{0}^{5} f(x) dx \\
&=2 \cdot \int_{0}^{1} f(x) dx + 2 \cdot \int_{1}^{5} f(x) dx \\
&= 6+ 2 \cdot \int_{0}^{1} f(x) dx \\
&= 6+ 2 \cdot \int_{-4}^{-5} f(x) dx \\
&= 6+ 2 (-2) \\
&= 2
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Let $I = \int_{5}^{15}f(x)dx$. Then, do the substitution $x \mapsto x+5$, to have $I = \int_{0}^{10}f(x+5)dx=\int_{0}^{10}f(x)dx$. Do the same substitution to have $I=\int_{-5}^{5}f(x)dx$. Now, let $J = \int_{-5}^{-4}f(x)dx$. Do the substitution $x \mapsto x-5$ to have $J = \int_{0}^{1}f(x-5)dx = \int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx$ ($ \forall x (f(x)=f(x+5)) \iff  \forall x(f(x)=f(x-5))$). Now, we have, $1=J+\int_{1}^{5}f(x)dx=\int_{0}^{5}f(x)dx$. Do the substitution $x \mapsto x+5$, to have $1 = \int_{-5}^{0}f(x)dx$. Now, $I=\int_{-5}^{0}f(x)dx + \int_{0}^{5}f(x)dx=1+1=2$.